# How to write a while() loop in Gforth

Tags: forth, gforth

I'd like to write a while() loop in [Gforth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gforth). Unfortunately, [the only tutorial online](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/Simple-Loops.html#Simple-Loops) isn't useful due to a lack of examples, and examples on counted loops (what I'm not looking for) appear fundamentally different.

What are some concrete examples of how to represent something like this?

```
while (x > 3) { print(x); x--; }
```

Or really, just some concrete way to represent anything of the form:

```
while (predicate) { expression(s) }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your first piece of code translates to:

```
\ Assuming x is on the top of the stack.
begin dup 3 > while dup . 1- repeat

\ Or if x is in memory.
begin x @ 3 > while x ? -1 x +! repeat
```

And the second:

```
begin predicate while expressions repeat
```